# How do you run a Word mail merge macro from Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I have a macro in an Excel workbook that currently does the following:

1. Create a data.csv file with data in the first two rows (for a mail merge)
2. Pull a template of a selected Word document and make the data.csv file the source for the mail merge
3. If the user chooses, it finishes the merge for the document
4. If the user chooses, it opens the document when the macro is complete. If they don't choose to open, the word documents all close.

I've been running into a couple major issues:

1. The macro only seems to run smoothly if Word is entirely closed beforehand. My current workaround is a popup message if Word is open, telling the user to close word, but this is not ideal because it disrupts flow for some users who may have several instances of Word open.
2. The macro has been running slowly, especially for some of the document templates that have thousands of merge fields pre-entered in the template. It sometimes take longer than a minute, and sometimes completely freezes.

Would the macro would run more smoothly if I have the Excel VBA open the Word template and have most of the code for setting up and finishing the mail merge in Word VBA? I'm much less familiar with Word VBA - can anyone help me with bringing over my code to word (but still initiated by Excel)? Also, if you can figure out why the macro struggles when Word is already open, I'd greatly appreciate it.

I didn't include the entire code for proprietary reasons, but please let me know if there's something else you need to see.

Thank you!!

```
Sub Mail_Merge_Dynamic()
    Dim mergeFile, tempFilePath As String
    Dim WordDoc, WordApp As Object
    Dim tempPath, mergePath, finalPath, curDir As String
    Dim mergeFilePath, finalFilePath As String
    Dim dataPath, FileNameCell, PrincCertCell, MMPrefix As String
    Dim FileCount As Integer
    Dim Close_Choice, ActiveWindow As String
    Dim WarningMsg, WarningMsg2 As String
    Dim NotFound, Overwrite1, Overwrite2 As Boolean
    
Dim oBook As Workbook

'Update csv file for Data Merge
    narrative_merge
    Call WarpSpeed_On
    Sheets("Navigation").Select
    Range("Merge_File_1").Select
    
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    
'//////////////////////////////MAIL MERGE MACRO\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
'Set up Mail Merge Documents from Template Folder based on selections on Navigation tab
    For i = 1 To FileCount
        FileNameCell = "Merge_File_" & i
        If Range(FileNameCell) = "" Then
        Else
            mergeFile = Range(FileNameCell)
            
           
            tempFilePath = tempPath & mergeFile
    
            mergeFilePath = mergePath & "MM_" & mergeFile
            finalFilePath = finalPath & mergeFile
                
'Activate Mail Merge
            If Range("MM_Activate") = 0 Then
            Else
                Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(tempFilePath)
                
                With WordDoc.MailMerge
                    .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
        
                'Set up the mail merge data source
                    dataPath = curDir & "\data.csv"
                    .OpenDataSource Name:=dataPath
                    
                'Show values in the mail merge fields
                    .ViewMailMergeFieldCodes = wdToggle
                End With
                
                'WordDoc.ShowFieldCodes = False
                'WordDoc.MailMerge.ViewMailMergeFieldCodes = False
                
                WordDoc.SaveAs FileName:=mergeFilePath
        
            End If
              
' Finish mail merge
            If Range("MM_Finish") = 0 Then
            Else
                With WordDoc.MailMerge
                    .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
                    .SuppressBlankLines = True
                    .Execute Pause:=False
                End With
            
                WordDoc.Application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs finalFilePath
            End If
                
        End If
    Next i
       
Call CloseWordDocuments
    
'Make word visible if an Open command has been selected
If Range("MM_Open_Merge") = 1 Or Range("MM_Open_Doc") = 1 Then
    curDir = ThisWorkbook.Path
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    
    For i = 1 To FileCount
        FileNameCell = "Merge_File_" & i
        If Range(FileNameCell) = "" Then
        Else
        
        mergeFile = Range(FileNameCell)
          
        mergeFilePath = curDir & "\Merge-Active Forms\" & "MM_" & mergeFile
        finalFilePath = curDir & "\Merge-Complete Forms\" & mergeFile
            
            If Range("MM_Open_Merge") = 1 Then
                Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(mergeFilePath)
            End If
            
            If Range("MM_Open_Doc") = 1 Then
                Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(finalFilePath)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    WordApp.Visible = True
    'Windows(mergeFile).Activate
    
End If

GoTo Reset
Reset:
Call WarpSpeed_Off
      

End Sub


Sub WarpSpeed_On_Calcs_Off()

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  
' Turn off display alerts
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub

Sub WarpSpeed_On()

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  
' Turn off display alerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End Sub


Sub WarpSpeed_Off()

'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a quick comment on your code. Your variable declarations are incorrect. For example; in the line `Dim tempPath, mergePath, finalPath, curDir As String` only `curDir` is declared as a string. The others are untyped which means they inherit the default datatype of variant.

Comment: Have you compared the time it takes to run those large mail-merge documents via the UI? You only have a performance problem with your code if it takes significantly longer than the UI to do the same operation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about variable declarations. So they each need their own line? @TimothyRylatt

Comment: @TimothyRylatt The UI is slow (5-10 seconds for the large mail-merge documents), but the code definitely seems to be bugging out on something and taking a lot longer.

Comment: Variable declarations don’t need to be on their own line, but do need to be typed e.g. `Dim tempPath as String, mergePath as String, finalPath as String, curDir As String`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

this will open Word if it is not already open:

```
Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
```

**Edit#1**

In VBA you may do something like:

```
  On Error GoTo CreateObj
  ' Is Word application already running ?
  Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
  GoTo gotApp
CreateObj:
  ' Not running, create first instance:
  Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
gotApp:
  On Error GoTo 0 ' disable error handling
  ' continue
  ....
  ....
```

Comment: I switched the command as you suggested but this error came up when running that line of code: 
"Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object"

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: If Word application is not running then create a first instance with CreateObject.